# Windows presentation layer using c# and .net hardware requirements

Tags: hardware, requirements, kiosk

All,

If I were to develop a kiosk app using Windows presentation foundation, c# and .net, what hardware requirements would I need. I plan on making it a standalone desktop app. It would contain images, and about 1-2 minutes of video. What kind of CPU (pentium, dual-core, what clock speed, graphic card?, memory? )

What if I made the kiosk a web app? What hardware requirements would I need?

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: @Jean-Bernard - I assume the OP means the hardware required to run the application.

Comment: depends a lot on which version of windows you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer, but I would go with the cheapest actual PC configuration.  Your software will probably run on an actual 300$ budget PC.

If you need more proof and want to go with older PC.  Test it on a relative PC, I'm sure you could find someone with a P4. ;-)  Else just buy one used (probably for 50$).